# Weird __COUNTER__ behavior on LLVM

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, c-preprocessor, llvm

I'm trying to understand what could cause this problem because everything seems to be fine but the result seems to point out some sort of buggy behavior.

I have a custom struct defined as:

```
struct MyStruct {
  const u16 index;
  ...

  MyStruct(u16 index) : index(index), ... { }
}

static const MyStruct array[] = {
 MyStruct(__COUNTER__,...),
 MyStruct(__COUNTER__,...),
 MyStruct(__COUNTER__,...)
 ...
}
```

Now, if I check the preprocessed file with XCode everything is fine and I get incremental indices as they are supposed to be.

At runtime, instead, what happens is that the index 16 becomes 23 and the successive indices are lowered by one, eg:

```
real index         stored index

0                   0
1                   1
2                   2
3                   3
4                   4
5                   5
6                   6
7                   7
8                   8
9                   9
10                  10
11                  11
12                  12
13                  13
14                  14
15                  15
16                  23
17                  16
18                  17
19                  18
20                  19
```

This is quite curious, especially because 16 seems to be a specific bound. Compiler is Apple  Clang 4.2 (based on LLVM 3.2), on XCode 4.6.

Comment: As an aside, why are you still using Xcode 4.6?

Comment: Can you run preprocessor (`-E` option of clang) and post its results here or on some "text hosting" site? `__COUNTER__` is preprocessor macro and expanded early in translation, [in `Preprocessor::ExpandBuiltinMacro` .. `if (II == Ident__COUNTER__)`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/tags/RELEASE_32/final/lib/Lex/PPMacroExpansion.cpp) as simple counter.